# Video Streaming Server - playback of streamed data on HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, video

How do I get access to a video which is getting streamed from a STREAMING source i.e a video streaming server? I would want to play this video stream on a HTML5 compatible browser. I could upload a video onto a video hosting site myself - that would involve some costs as most of the sites are not free. Are there any video streaming servers which I can access for free?

Comment: right now HTML5 by default only plays back from progressive download sources, not a streaming source. There are some efforts being made to leverage the new MediaSource API to support things like DASH eg http://francisshanahan.com/index.php/2013/build-an-mpeg-dash-player-from-scratch/

Comment: @ Offbeatmammal : Thanks for the help and info. From your comment, Is it right that if we use players like video.js or frameworks like popcorn.js - html5 would still play the video as a  PROGRESSIVE DOWNLOAD ? Could you please tell me what other options we have for playback from a streaming source.

Comment: for Streaming video - HLS or SmoothStreaming for instance - Flash or Silverlight are the only reliable, cross browser mechanisms